# Custom HttpModule Installation on Live Server

Tags: c#, iis

I have a custom HttpModule implemented for a site I am working on. It is designed to perform an action on the **PreSendRequestContent** event. When I run the debugger and built in Visual Studio Server it runs without any problems. BUt when I publish it to the Live Server it doesn't. I am using a Classic Mode configuration of IIS meaning that I should only have to add the module to the **web.config** file. Am I missing something?

namespace SmartBilling
{

```
public class HttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HttpModule()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
    {
        // Register our event handler with Application object.
        httpApplication.PreSendRequestContent += new EventHandler(httpApplication_PreSendRequestContent);
    }

    void httpApplication_PreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Left blank because we dont have to do anything.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your module declaration.

Comment: @Alexn: here you go :) Thanks

Comment: What does your entry in web.config look like?

Comment: I found the problem is that I am expecting this Module to get called for static files, which does not happen automatically. Need to find a way to get IIS to call this module for non asp.net extensions.